# changing locale not effect on font type

Tags: java, android

I have two font directories (fa/en) for two type of languages.
In my app setting user can change the app language.
I save its changes in preferences and start main activity.
in main activity before super.oncreate in first line of oncreate method i change locale accornding to saved language in preferences.
language of app changes but font not changes !!!
after close and open app again .. changes in fonts are done.

change language with this code .

```
    private void configAppLanguage(){
        String lang = PrefManager.getLanguage();
        Locale locale = new Locale(lang);
        Locale.setDefault(locale);
        Configuration config = new Configuration();
        config.locale = locale;

        getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,
                getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

    }
```

start main activity with this code .

```
Intent intent = new Intent(LanguageActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Have you solved this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget that, if you change the locale with a running Activity, you will need to restart it for the changes to take effect.
Just for a clear answer some code I use (changed for your context):

```
@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
    super.attachBaseContext(updateBaseContextLocale(base));
}

private Context updateBaseContextLocale(Context context) {
    final String language = PrefManager.getLanguage(); // Your helper method to get saved language
    final Locale locale = new Locale(language);
    Locale.setDefault(locale);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        return updateResourcesLocale(context, locale);
    }

    return updateResourcesLocaleLegacy(context, locale);
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N_MR1)
private Context updateResourcesLocale(Context context, Locale locale) {
    Configuration configuration = new Configuration(context.getResources().getConfiguration())
    configuration.setLocale(locale);
    return context.createConfigurationContext(configuration);
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
private Context updateResourcesLocaleLegacy(Context context, Locale locale) {
    final Resources resources = context.getResources();
    Configuration configuration = resources.getConfiguration();
    configuration.locale = locale;
    resources.updateConfiguration(configuration, resources.getDisplayMetrics());
    return context;
}
```

Every time your activity starts the method *attachBaseContext(Context base)* gets called and updates your language.

I hope I could help you. Cheers!

Comment: thanks . but font not changed although language is changed ... in reopening the app changes in fonts accured

Comment: So my code snippets worked? If not post your activity where you want to change the language and we will work on a solution.

Comment: @AliDelavari found any solution? i am facing same issue.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change locale and return context to `attachBaseContext`

- This `Kotlin` method change locale

```
 fun setLocale(context: Context, lang: String): Context {
        val locale = Locale(lang)
        Locale.setDefault(locale)
        val config = context.resources.configuration
        config.setLocale(locale)

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
            return context.createConfigurationContext(config)
        else
            context.resources.updateConfiguration(config, context.resources.displayMetrics)
        return context
    }
```

- Now call `setLocale`  in activity `attachBaseContext` to apply locale related resources when activity launches.

```
   override fun attachBaseContext(base: Context?) {
        val locale = "ar" // you might read saved locale code from preferences
        super.attachBaseContext(setLocale(base, locale))
    }
```

- Or restart your activity if you want change locale on runtime.

```
startActivity(getIntent())
finish()
```